# Baffling InnoDB deadlock

Tags: mysql, innodb, deadlock, database-deadlocks

This InnoDB deadlock is really making me pull my hair. As far as I can see:

1. the transaction (1) is waiting for the PRIMARY on "applications"
2. The latter has been acquired by (2) for some rather long running updates (SELECT * FROM applications WHERE ID = xxxx FOR UPDATE)

So far, so good - one would expect (1) to wait for the lock and then get on with its work.

However, once (2) gets ready to save it's work (and commit the transaction), it fails with a deadlock since for some reason (1) has managed to get a lock on some secondary index. **How the hell did (1) manage to get any locks on the row if the PRIMARY is being held by (2).**

One would expect that if (2) originally acquired the PRIMARY lock (SELECT * FROM applications WHERE ID = xxxx FOR UPDATE) it would also have set locks on all the secondary indexes. Is it possible that it will not lock the "tasked" index if tasked==NULL thus allowing (1) acquire a lock on "tasked" before even getting a lock on PRIMARY?

I have had no luck replication this scenario..

Thank you!

Lauri

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
130428 17:04:06
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION A369A8C, ACTIVE 1 sec fetching rows
mysql tables in use 3, locked 3
LOCK WAIT 217 lock struct(s), heap size 31160, 636 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 13310554, OS thread handle 0x7f06cc2d7700, query id 177699568 217.146.78.151 shard67 Sending data
SELECT `applications`.* FROM `applications`
 LEFT JOIN `applicants` ON applicants.ID = applications.applicant_ID
 LEFT JOIN `regions` ON regions.ID = applicants.region_ID WHERE (status <> 'Blank') AND (status <> 'Closed') AND (revised < 1367154245) AND (tasked IS NULL OR tasked < 1367147045) AND (commence_year >= '2013') AND (regions.instance_ID = '1') ORDER BY `tasked` ASC, `ID` ASC LIMIT 20 FOR UPDATE
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 20021 page no 1192 n bits 80 index `PRIMARY` of table `dream-shard67`.`applications` trx id A369A8C lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION A369A87, ACTIVE 1 sec updating or deleting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
16 lock struct(s), heap size 3112, 22 row lock(s), undo log entries 5
MySQL thread id 13310563, OS thread handle 0x7f06cc151700, query id 177699599 217.146.76.127 shard67
UPDATE `applications` SET `revised` = '1367157846', `tasked` = '1367157846', `revision_ID` = '140649', `xml` = 'Zms6\noMmI$%[v....snipped binary data
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 20021 page no 1192 n bits 72 index `PRIMARY` of table `dream-shard67`.`applications` trx id A369A87 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 20021 page no 292 n bits 1280 index `tasked` of table `dream-shard67`.`applications` trx id A369A87 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your doing most of these:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-deadlocks.html